# Subir mas de 100 registro, con la api de google drive aun documento

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api, google-drive

Tengo la siguiente situación,estoy usando la **API** de **Google Drive** para crear una tabla con **Google Service Sheets**. El documento lo crea sin problema, cuando comienzo a subir los registros y llego al registro 100, me envía un mensaje que me dice que he excedido la cuota de registro a subir. Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna forma de poder subir más de 100 registros a través de **API** de **Google Drive**?

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code":
>   429, "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit
>   'USER-100s' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer
>   'project_number:569124525622'.", "errors": [ { "message": "Quota
>   exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service
>   'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:569124525622'.",
>   "domain": "global", "reason": "rateLimitExceeded" } ], "status":
>   "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" } } in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/distrivucion/lib/gdriver/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 118

**Función para subir los ficheros**

```
$i = 5;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data = [[$row['xxxx1'],$row['nnnn1'],$nBulto,$row['llll1']]];
       $range = "A".$i.":K".$i;
       updateFileDoc($driveService,$range,$fileId,$data);
       $i++;
}
```

**Función updateFileDoc**

```
function  updateFileDoc($service,$range,$spreadsheetId,$values){
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'values' => $values
    ]);
    $params = [
        'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
    ];
    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range,
    $body, $params);
    return $result->getUpdatedCells();
}
```

Comment: tendrás que refactorizar para hacer todos los cambios de una con un [batchupdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate) o limitar los requests a [menos de 100 cada 100 segundos](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)

Comment: Gracias por el comentario,  tengo una duda la cantidad de registro que quiero actualizar es de 3000 registro. En esta caso el **batchupdate**  tiene algún limite porque no veo si tiene limite o no en la documentación

Comment: batchupdate es para enviar varios rangos en una sola petición. en tu caso habrias de cambiar el updatefiledoc del while para que guarde en memoria cada rango por separado (en vez de aplicarlo cada vez con el update) y al finalizar el while los aplique todos con un solo batch (asumiendo que el spreadsheetID es el mismo para todos los rangos).